# Java does not print decimal places

Tags: java

I'm trying to do a very basic operation as follows:

```
double a=21/5;
System.out.println(a);
```

However, each time I get `4.0` as the output and not `4.2`. I'm encountering this for the first time. I've been using Java for years, but never came across this obscurity.

Comment: The division is an Integer division, so 21/5 = 4, then casted to Double, so 4.0.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Obviously! Damn my brain. Thanks for rescuing it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: That was an *answer*, not a comment. One I'd've upvoted. :-)

Comment: Meh, you got 6 other ones to choose from.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: None which bothered to explain what was going on, though, you see. :-) (Even now, the edited versions of the ones there are still not nearly as good.) That's why I made the comment, nice to see *good* answers.

Comment: `int` / `int` = `int`. You are then casting the `int` result to a `double`

Answer (score 10):

You are using integer division, which result will always be integer
You should use something like this.

```
double a=(double)21/5;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are doing integer division...

Try:

```
double a = 21.0/5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the division or specify one of the arguments as a decimal to force the return as a double:

```
double a = (double)21/5;
```

-or-

```
double a = 21.0/5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cast one of the numbers to double:

```
double a = 21/5.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Force the cast to double.
`double a = 21.0/5`

This is called Arithmetic promotion. This means that all terms in an equation are made equal to the variable type with the highest precision. In this case double.